# Google Ads suddenly stopped working after few months [Android][iOS][Flutter]

Tags: android, ios, flutter, admob, google-ads-api

I had ***banner, interstitial, and reward ads*** on one of my apps. The ads seemed to have been working for the past 2 months and then suddenly yesterday both android and iOS apps stopped showing ads:

iOS Error: `code: 1, domain: com.google.admob, message: Request Error: No ad to show`

Android: `code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config`

It's also strange that both the apps have different error codes.

Package: `google_mobile_ads: ^0.12.1+1`

Code:

```dart
Container(
     height: bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
     child: AdWidget(
            ad: bannerAd,
            ),
     margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
)
```

Note:

1. The ***test ads*** seem to work just fine.
2. The Android and iOS apps have been published on the stores and have been working just fine for the past 2 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your test ads are working fine, means their is nothing to worry, your implementation is correct, just cross check your ads ids is correct and on place.

> Something, i want to mention here that the ads are user specific and
> may be for you ads are not available at some moments, Just check with
> other users or other devices.
>
> Also check your admob account for any limit putted by admob due to unwanted traffic or may be for some other reason.

You can wait for sometime, if their is any limit putted by admob will be automatically removed.

**Suggestion**
Don't click on any ads from your side and also don't increase ad traffic on your account from one device

Comment: what happens if you click on one of your own ads? I may have done this...

Comment: If you are frequently clicking on yours ads then their is possibility that your admob account may get blocked, Google having strong algorithm to find a difference between valid and invalid clicks and traffic

Answer (score 1):

Error Code 3 : ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL
Description : The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Why is  it Happening : Advertisers can target specific regions, platforms and user profiles based on business relevance, which can sometimes result in lower availability of Ads for a particular region or user profile. Error code suggests that the implementation is correct, and that the Ad Request was not filled because of lack of availability of a suitable Ad at that particular instant of time when an Ad Request was sent from the app.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because, the ads might no be available at the moment. As there will be a limit for the ads that you render in your applications. Please wait for a while or just ping the product analysis [team](https://support.google.com/admob/gethelp).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response, unfortunately, I have tried contacting the admobs support team but when trying to send them a mail, it shows "Something went wrong. Please try again".

Answer (score 0):

It happens to my admobs as well. They do not always have ads available. What I started doing was testing for an ad from admobs and if non available, I use an ad from somebody else.